# Count and group equal values ​in the same cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, countif

In Google Sheets I want to create a formula that separates the values ​​separated by "|" in the "Memory" column and count the same values, so that the result is the same as in the "Result" column:

| Memory | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 4GB | 4GB | 8GB | 8GB | 8GB | 8GB | 4GB | 3 x 4GB + 4 x 8GB |
| 4GB | 1 x 4GB |
| 4GB | 8GB | 1 x 4GB + 1 x 8GB |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula like this, that splits the values and makes the count:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(mem,IF(mem="",,
LET(splitted,SPLIT(mem," | "),
uniq, UNIQUE(TOCOL(splitted)),
counts, BYROW(uniq,LAMBDA(each,COUNTIF(splitted,each)&" x "&each)),
TEXTJOIN(" + ",1,counts)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;let(Λ;split(Σ;" | ";0);Δ;unique(Λ;1);join(" + ";index(countif(Λ;Δ)&" x "&Δ))))))
```

[image]